# Using bash, separate servers into separate file depending on even or odd numbers

Tags: bash

The output comes from a command I run from our netscaler. It outputs the following ... One thing to note is that the middle two numbers change but the even/odd criteria is always on the last digit. We never have more than 2 digits, so we'll never hit 10.

```
WC-01-WEB1
WC-01-WEB4
WC-01-WEB3
WC-01-WEB5
WC-01-WEB8
```

I need to populate a file called "even" and "odds." If we're dealing with numbers I can figure it out, but having the number within a string is throwing me off.

Example code but I'm missing the part where I need to match the string.

```
if [ $even_servers -eq 0 ] 
then
    echo $line >> evenfile 
else
    echo $line >> oddfile
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `awk` command:

```
awk '/[02468]$/{print > "evenfile"}; /[13579]$/{print > "oddfile"}' input.txt
```

There must be better way.

Answer (score 1):

How about this version:

```
for v in `cat <my_file>`; do export type=`echo $v | awk -F 'WEB' '{print $2%2}'`; if [ $type -eq 0 ]; then echo $v >> evenfile ; else echo $v >> oddfile; fi; done
```

I assume your list of servers is stored in the filename `<my_file>`. The basic idea is to tokenize on `WEB` using `awk` and process the chars after `WEB` to determine even-ness. Once this is known, we `export` the value to a variable `type` and use this to selectively dump to the appropriate file.

For the case when the name is the output of another command:

```
export var=`<another command>`; export type=`echo $var | awk -F 'WEB' '{print $2%2}'`; if [ $type -eq 0 ]; then echo $var >> evenfile ; else echo $var >> oddfile; fi;
```

Replace `<another command>` with your perl script.

Comment: It actually comes from the output of a perl command. I can pipe the output to a series of other commands.

Comment: @luckytaxi, I have added an update to the code to handle your case.

Answer (score 0):

As always grep is your friend:

```
grep "[2468]$" input_file > evenfile
grep "[^2468]$" input_file > oddfile
```

I hope this helps.